# php $_GET ["variable"] isn't set even though it should be

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

in my php file I have this:

```
<script>var editMode = 
<?php if(isset($_Get["e"])){
        if($_Get["e"]){
            echo "true";
        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }
?>;</script>
```

but when I visit the page with (my domain name)/EditMap.php?e=true the php code executed the echo "0" line which means for some reason it isnt getting the value of e from the url.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `$_GET['e']` instead of `$_Get['e']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper syntax for GET ie. `$_GET`

```
<script>var editMode = 
<?php if(isset($_GET["e"])){
        if($_GET["e"]){
            echo "true";
        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }
?>;</script>
```